# Integration of a Custom Trained YOLO Model with OpenCV for Video Object Detection

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, yolov8

I have recently trained a YOLO (You Only Look Once) model and saved the weights in a .pt file. Now, I'm trying to use this trained YOLO model to perform real-time object detection on a video stream using OpenCV2. I've gone through the YOLO documentation, but I'm still unsure about the integration process with OpenCV2.

Current Progress:

- Model Training: The YOLO model has been trained for our specific use-case and the resulting weights are stored in a .pt file.
- Environment Setup: PyTorch and OpenCV2 are installed and functioning correctly in the development environment.
- Model Loading: The model is loaded into the Python environment using PyTorch.

I am currently encountering difficulties in the following areas:

- Frame Extraction: Efficiently extracting frames from a video stream using OpenCV2 for processing.
- Frame Preprocessing: Appropriately preprocessing the extracted frames to align with the input requirements of the YOLO model.
- Detection and Localization: Implementing the detection process on each frame and localizing objects using the YOLO model.
- Output Visualization: Display of the video frames with bounding boxes and annotations for identified objects from the pre-recorded video file.

Here is my `configuration.yaml` file if you need more information:

```yaml
# YOLOv8 Configuration File for Car License Plate Recognition with 432 Images

# Model Configuration
model:
  architecture: yolov8  # YOLOv8 architecture

# Training Configuration
path: /Users/<USER>/Desktop/testing_vehicle_license_recognition
train: dataset/images
val: dataset/images

# Model Save/Load Configuration
save_model_path: build/model.pth  # Path to save the trained model

# Other Configurations
names:
  0: ['license_plate']

# Evaluation Configuration
iou_threshold: 0.5  # IoU threshold for evaluation

# Training Logs
log_path: logs  # Path to save training logs

# GPU Configuration
use_gpu: true  # Set to false if using CPU
gpu_device: 0  # GPU device index

# Miscellaneous
conf_threshold: 0.3  # Confidence threshold for predictions
```